# How do I use Ternary operation to change the value of a field in <td>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to get the status to change to shared if it's userA and if isshared is true. However, with the code I have below, it's returning shared for every field, even when isShared is false.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getLocalStorageStore } from "@/store/localStorage/utils";

const FileResults: React.FC<FileResultType> = props => {
  const { results, filename, status = "shared" } = props;

  const { email = "", isShared = false } = useSelector(getLocalStorageStore);
  const isUserA = email.toLowerCase().includes("usera");

  return (
    <>
      <tr className="file-result">
        <td>{results || "--"}</td>
        <td>{filename || "--"}</td>
        <td>{isUserA && isShared === true ? status : "private"}</td>
      </tr>
    </>
  );
};

export default FileResults;
```

Note: this is what I have in my FileResultType

```
export interface FileResultType {
  results: string;
  filename: string;
  status: string;
}
```

Comment: It's always good practice to include parentheses to indicate order of operations: `( isUserA && ( isShared === true ) ) ? status : "private"`.

Comment: The type `React.FC` is deprecated, use `React.FunctionComponent`